# Is there any value to this patent for the inventor?

Tags: us7006778

Is there any value to this [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7006778B2/en) for the inventors? They were all Xerox employees at the time, but are retired now

Comment: what difference does it make?

Answer (score 1):

When you work for a company, the standard employment agreement (at least in the US) is that the company owns the results of your work. Thus when you invent something while working, the company owns the rights to that invention. As you can see with this patent, the assignee is Xerox Corporation. Many companies reward inventors with an award of some sort when a patent issues, but beyond that, the value of this patent belongs completely with the assignee, Xerox and not the inventors.